# BindingOperations.ClearBinding(...) doesn't work when control is from a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm a bit stuck on this one. Clearing the binding of the `TextProperty` of some `TextBox` that is not part of a `DataTemplate` works fine. But when the `TextBox` is part of a `DataTemplate`, clearing the binding seems to be a no-op as shown in the snip below. The watch value is `true` even after the binding is presumably cleared:

[image]

Is this by design? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the MSDN documentation of `ClearBinding(...)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearbinding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e45c7a9d-840d-4508-8c81-ef40f1c74c10) that covers the issue. While it seems to leave the issue without a real explanation, it does provide a workaround that seems to work just fine.

I replace the ClearBinding invocation with replacing the binding with some dummy value:

```
AssociatedObject.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "dummy");
```

Now it seems that this will break when the control is not from a `DataTemplate`. So to work-around that, and so cover `TextBox`es from `DataTemplate` and otherwise, I now do this:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty);
if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty))
    AssociatedObject.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "dummy");
```

And voila, the binding is "severed" and so my watermark seems to work just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work (didn't try), but please try using `BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings()` method as stated in this excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearbinding.aspx) (see below how MSDN *refers* to Data Template):

> Clearing the binding removes the binding so that the value of the
>   dependency property is changed to whatever it would have been without
>   the binding. This value could be a default value, an inherited value,
>   or a value from a data template binding.
>
> To clear bindings from all possible properties on an object, use
>   `ClearAllBindings`.

Comment: I'll try it because it's easily done, but I fail to see how this would do anything differently.